# Can we catch an Error in Java?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

If you run following code then it will compile and run successfully,

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // insert code here
        try {
            new Example().go();
            // throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    void go() {
        go();
    }
}
```

With following output :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

So my question is **"Can we catch an Error"**..??

Comment: We can catch an error, yes

Comment: catch Throwable it will catch both exception and error. But seriously its not a good practice. U should fix asap as soon as there is error in your code. To print in catch block use System.out.err("java.lang.StackOverflowError");

Comment: your code just did. it even printed out your error, see?

Answer (score 6):

Answer to your question is yes, you can catch error in java. And your code is almost correct. Your method `go()` calls itself infinitely and therefore causes `StackOverflowError` that is caught in your catch block and printed by `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can catch an `Error`, but you are advised not to do it, since `Error`s indicate `serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch`. (as stated in the Javadoc of `Error`)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can catch an error.

The `Throwable` class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language. Only objects that are instances of this class (or one of its subclasses) are thrown by the Java Virtual Machine or can be thrown by the `throw` statement.

Similarly, only this class or one of its subclasses can be the argument type in a `catch` clause. For the purpose of compile-time checking of exceptions, `Throwable` and any subclass of `Throwable` that is not also a subclass of either `RuntimeException` or `Error` are regarded as checked exceptions.

```
try {
    while(true) {

    }
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // TODO: handle exception

    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that there's a difference between `StackOverflowException` and `StackOverflowError`, since you have an **error**, it's a serious indication that you should never try to catch it.

Just don't do infinite things in your code, when this error happens, no stack space is available, how would you want to proceed?

`StackOverFlowError` indicates that you have severe problems, it's a bad idea to catch this error, instead, try to understand what problems you have in your code and fix them.

Comment: There is nothing called StackOverflowException. There is only StackOverflow error